# How to iterate over multiple lists

Tags: flutter, dart

With the code below I'm trying to loop through values in both list and have each element in the list respecitively mapped as values of a dynamic radioListTile like so:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.shoeName.split(',').length; i++)
                             RadioListTile(
                                title: Text(data.shoeName.split(',')[i]),
                                subtitle: Text(data.shoePrice.split(',')[i]),
                                })
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future please provide code snippets with more context.

I would guess you want something like the following:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class YOUR_DATA_TYPE {
  late String shoeName;
  late String shoePrice;
}

List<RadioListTile<int>> buildYourList(YOUR_DATA_TYPE data, void Function(int?) onChanged, int selectedValue) {
  final List<String> shoeNames = data.shoeName.split(','); // 1. create lists from data
  final List<String> shoePrices = data.shoePrice.split(',');
  final List<RadioListTile<int>> radioTiles = <RadioListTile<int>>[]; // 2. create return list
  for (int i = 0; i < min(shoeNames.length, shoePrices.length); i++) {
    // 3. loop over lists and add output 
    radioTiles.add(RadioListTile<int>(
      title: Text(shoeNames[i]),
      subtitle: Text(shoePrices[i]),
      value: i,
      groupValue: selectedValue,
      onChanged: onChanged,
    ));
  }
  return radioTiles;
}
```

You instead iterate over the minimum of the length of both list and then access the elements of both lists index based.

For a quick and dirty running example:

```dart
void main() {
  final YOUR_DATA_TYPE data = YOUR_DATA_TYPE();
  data.shoeName = "a,b,c,d,e";
  data.shoePrice = "1,2,3,4,5";
  int? selectedValue;

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, void Function(VoidCallback) setState) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text("your shoes"),
              ...buildYourList(data, (int? value) => setState(() => selectedValue = value), selectedValue),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```